# Getting around quotes inside Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel Formula that I'm using inside VBA. However, when I'm compiling it, VBA throws me an error.

I'm kind of certain that it is because of the quotes in my Formula.

```
Range("E2:E" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,$B:$B,1,FALSE)=D2,"Form Present"),"Not Present")"
```

This is what I tried to get around this,

```
 Range("E2:E" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,$B:$B,1,FALSE)=D2,&Chr(34)&Form Present&Chr(34)&),&Chr(34)&Not Present&Chr(34)&)"
```

I used chr(34) to generate a Quote symbol within however this is not working. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use

```
Range("E2:E" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,$B:$B,1,FALSE)=D2,""Form Present""),""Not Present"")"
```

or

```
Range("E2:E" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,$B:$B,1,FALSE)=D2," & Chr(34) & "Form Present" & Chr(34) & ")," & Chr(34) & "Not Present" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just double up quotation marks and change it to this:

```
 Range("E2:E" & lastRow).FormulaLocal "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,$B:$B,1,FALSE)=D2,""Form Present""),""Not Present"")"
```

This fails `"=IF(1=1,"Y","N")"` , whereas this works `"=IF(1=1,""Y"",""N"")"`